# Add a Tap Event on a map pin in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8.1 Store App about a public bus transport service, that reads the coordinates of every bus stop from a Database stored on Windows Azure, and for each coordinates the program draw a Pin.

The code is the following:

```
private async void addImageToMap(Geopoint geopoint)
        {
            string title;
            title = this.resourceLoader.GetString("NoGPSTitle");
            Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            Geoposition geoposition = null;

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Width = 40;
            image.Height = 40;
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/mapPinBlu.png");
            image.Source = bitmapImage;
            geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            MapControl.SetLocation(image, geopoint);
            MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(image, new Point(0.25, 0.9));


            myMapControl.Children.Clear();
            myMapControl.Children.Add(image);


            title = this.resourceLoader.GetString("Voisietequi");

        }
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to add an event this pin, and even reading other discussions I wasn't able to understand how I can do it...

I need to create an event that when I click on the Pin it show's a message like "Pin Clicked" as example...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Rather than draw an image like this, style a pin in xaml. Insert a new user-control into your App, then draw it in xaml, write the code behind in the xaml.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is setting everything in your view XAML.
There is a control called `MapItemsControl`and it can be used to bind to a collection of items. If needed you can also style each so that it uses your given image.
For a good example you can take a look at Shawn Kendrot's site here: http://visuallylocated.com/post/2014/08/13/Bind-a-collection-of-items-to-the-Windows-Phone-MapControl.aspx

Other thing to add is a `tapped` event on that collection to handle it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but it's possible to do the same with an image created from code instead XAML?

Because for the implementation  of my program it's easier manage it in code instead XAML.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok. So how can I link the data taken from my online database on Azure (data are coordinates) wrote in C# and the UI XAML code?

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If you follow the link to Shawn's blog it should be enough to get you started. But if you are not familiar with MVVM, best is to check out some tutorials online like this one http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2014/06/30/.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add a Tapped event to your map in your XAML. It seems like MapTapped triggers when map is tapped, and Tapped when map child tapped.